# Fetching the total amount of SE reputation accumulated

Tags: r, list

Since I am new to R, I have pulled this code together in kind of a rag-tag way, but I am wondering, is there something similar to list comprehensions (in Python) I can use in R to make this simpler?  Basically, can I loop through all items from a list, only keep one subitem, then apply `sum` to the list new, unwrapped list?

I am trying to fetch the total amount of reputation a user has accumulated on Stack Exchange.  I am ideally looking for a way to remove the `for` loop and use the `sum` function on reputation which is contained by items (from the API response).

```
library(httr)
s = 0
for(i in content(GET(paste("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/",readline(),"/associated",sep="")))$items) {
  q=i$reputation
  if (q>101) 
    s=s+q
}
print(s)
```

Sample input would be a user's id, like `10400443`.

Comment: `response <- GET(paste("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/",5688224,"/associated",sep=""));
repn <- sapply(content(response)$items, \`[[\`, 'reputation');
sum(repn[repn > 101])`

Comment: @alistaire thanks!

Comment: or with purrr, `response %>% content() %>% .$items %>% map_int('reputation') %>% keep(~.x > 101) %>% sum()`